# network load and interarrival time

Tags: networking, time, load

I am a little confused by the definition of interarrival time, does it mean the time between two successfully sent packets? and by using opnet, I observed that the shorter the interarrival time is, the higher the network load, is that a correct conclusion? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: yes.

Interarrival time is defined as the time between the "start" of two events. (So if you had a network capable of processing two packets at the exact same time, and two packets come in, the interarrival time between those two packets would be zero.)

It sounds like you have some sort of monitoring utility measuring interarrival time. In that case, you should consult the documentation for the tool to see exactly what their definition is and how they calculate it.